# 英語が残っている: バッジを獲得した時の実績通知

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

[image: You've earned the badge]

Answer (score 1):

> （適用済）You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge ($badgeDescription$).

「$badgeName$」バッジを獲得しました（$badgeDescription$）

> （未翻訳）You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge ($badgeDescription$) for "$postTitle$".

「$badgeName$」バッジを「$postTitle$」で獲得しました（$badgeDescription$）

> （未翻訳）You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge ($badgeDescription$) for reviewing "$reviewQueueTitle$".

「$badgeName$」バッジを「$reviewQueueTitle$」のレビューで獲得しました（$badgeDescription$）

> （未翻訳）You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge ($badgeDescription$) for the "$tagName$" tag.

「$badgeName$」バッジを「$tagName$」タグで獲得しました（$badgeDescription$）

Answer (score 0):

バッジは複数ある為、下記のバリエーションがあります：

1. （未翻訳）You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge ($badgeDescription$) for "$postTitle$".
2. （未翻訳）You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge ($badgeDescription$) for reviewing "$reviewQueueTitle$".
3. （未翻訳）You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge ($badgeDescription$) for the "$tagName$" tag.
4. （適用済）You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge ($badgeDescription$).
5. You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge for reviewing Close Votes.
6. You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge for reviewing First Posts.
7. You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge for reviewing Flagged Posts ♦.
8. You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge for reviewing Late Answers.
9. You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge for reviewing Link Validation.
10. You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge for reviewing Low Quality Posts.
11. You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge for reviewing Reopen Votes.
12. You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge for reviewing Site Self-Evaluation.
13. You've earned the "$badgeName$" badge for reviewing Suggested Edits.
14. You've earned the "$badgeName$" tag badge.
15. You've earned the "$localizedBadgeName$" badge for $postLink$.
16. You've earned the "$localizedBadgeName$" badge for $tagLink$.
17. You've earned the "$localizedBadgeName$" badge for an election.
18. You've earned the "$localizedBadgeName$" badge for the tag synonym $tagSynonym$.
19. You've earned the "$localizedBadgeName$" badge.
20. You've earned the "$privilegeName$" privilege! Learn more about it in the help center.

5〜13は同じパターンですが、現在の日本語は：

> 「$badgeName$」バッジをクローズ票のレビューで獲得しました。

15〜17も同じパターンですが、現在の日本語は：

> 「$localizedBadgeName$」バッジを $postLink$ で獲得しました。

Comment: 未翻訳のものについて、訳案を私の回答に追加しました

Answer (score 0):

参考までに今日獲得しました。 "create tag synonyms" です。

**日本語版**  
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみに「「Enthusiast」バッジを獲得しました」 は本家の方のバッジ（連続アクセスしてないのがばれますね ^^; )なのですが、日本版にいると他のも翻訳された状態になるんですね。

以下は本家開いているときの同じ通知です。
（本家でもバッジが日本語訳されたら"create tag synonyms"だけ日本語になるんですかね？）

**英語版**  
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]